# Save meta value as an array of arrays

Tags: metabox, array

How to save metavalue in the following format:

```
array(
   array(
    'title' => 'something',
    'price' => 'something',
   ),
   array(
    'title' => 'something',
    'price' => 'something',
   ),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to query on the data, you can pass arrays directly to the post meta functions, WordPress will automatically serialize/unserialize the data for you.

```
$your_array = array(
   array(
    'title' => 'something',
    'price' => 'something',
   ),
   array(
    'title' => 'something',
    'price' => 'something',
   ),
);

update_post_meta( $post_id, 'your_key', $your_array );
```